# Datastax DevCenter Dialog Window Size Issue

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to use Datastax Devcenter for the first time. Unfortunately, no matter what I set my screen size to I am unable to see all of the text fields in the connection dialog window (see highlighted area in screenshot). It seems there are 4 "hidden" fields below the "Connection name" text field. I am unable to scroll to see them or tab into them to force them to scroll into view, nor is the dialog window resizable.

Would someone who is able to see them be kind enough to tell me what those "hidden" fields are?

[image: Window size]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create new connection dialog

I've attached a screenshot of the dialog. Unfortunately without entering at least a host I'm not sure you'll be able to get over this step. Please see the 2nd part for a possible workaround.

[image]

Could you please tell me:

1. what os are you using?
2. what's the screen resolution?

### Workaround

There might be a workaround for this issue, until it is fixed.

1. In your home directory, look for a file `.devcenter/connections/connectionList.xml`.
2. If it's missing create an empty one.
3. Add a connection details in the form described in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/al3xandru/272e0de1d399f6bae3d3)

   If you want to provide multiple hosts you can have multiple `<hosts>NODE IP</hosts>` elements.

Comment: Thanks very much! Using Windows 8.1. Screen resolution is (currently) set to 3200 x 1800.

Comment: @philburresseme I'm not a Windows user, but someone told me he was able to fix this by doing the following: Right click on “DevCenter.exe” => “Troubleshoot compatibility” => “Try recommended settings”

Comment: Compatibility mode did not work for me, but manually editing the connectionList.xml file did, which is all I need. Thanks for the help!